# Using Excel "IF" Statment To Filter Out Text Beginning Or Ending With A Certain Character

Tags: excel

Working on the same project as before and I need to find a way to to write an "IF" statement that will search for words beginning with a "<" as well as words that end with a " \ ".  I would like to conditionally highlight those cells with the value "IGNORE: HIDDEN FIELD".

I searched around and found that there is a `SEARCH` function in Excel but that doesn't seem to be what I'm looking for.

Is anyone aware of how to do this?  "If a cell begins with a "<" or ends with a " \ " then blah blah blah".

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To match words that start with `<` **and** end with `\`, use

`=IF(AND(LEFT(A1,1)="<",RIGHT(A1,1)="\"),TRUE,FALSE)`

To match words that start with `<` **and / or** end with `\`, use

`=IF(OR(LEFT(A1,1)="<",RIGHT(A1,1)="\"),TRUE,FALSE)`

Cell `A1` contains the word to test. This can form the basis of your conditional formatting test. If you want to display alternative text then replace `TRUE` and `FALSE` to suit personal taste, e.g. `IGNORE: HIDDEN FIELD` and `A1` respectively.

Answer (score 2):

Try,

```
=IF(OR(LEFT(A1)={"<","\"}),"blah-blah-blah", "")
```

That formula covers cell values beginning with either a *less than* or *backslash*. If the *backslash* should be checked at the end of the cell value then this would be more appropriate.

```
=IF(OR(LEFT(A1)="<",RIGHT(A1)="\"),"blah-blah-blah", "")
```

The `LEFT()` and `RIGHT()` functions default to a single character so if only the first character from either direction is to be examined the *num_chars* parameter is not required.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you can use `SEARCH()`

`=IF(OR(SEARCH("\";A1;1)=LEN(A1);SEARCH("<";A1;1)=1); "blahblahblah";"blahblahblah")`

Answer (score 0):

You could do the same job without IF

Replace function (<kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>) and "`*`" operator.

Press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>

Type "`<*`" to look for values that cells witch content begins with`<`
Than replace for whatever you want.

Type "`*/`" to find cells that's values end with `/`
Than replace it for whatever you want.

Or even better you could use Conditional Formating, it has one option for highlighting the cells that begins with a certain character.